# UIImageJPEGRepresentation compressionQuality vs other encoders

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, jpeg, libjpeg

How does the `compressionQuality` parameter in `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` related to similar parameters in other encoders such as libjpeg or ImageMagick?

When I try to use the same values in both ImageMagick and `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` I get totally different images sizes. I even tried WebP and it's size is much smaller that the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` result.

Comment: How do they compare when you pass in extreme values? (ie 0.0 which is maximum for `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and whatever the maximum is for ImageMagick)?

Comment: The original image is 3.9MB. For min/mid/max compression values the results are: iOS (181K/663K/4.4MB) IM (104K/291K/3.7MB)

Answer (score -1):

You are likely to get smaller image sizes with ImageMagick because it is a desktop program that can utilize the higher computing power to give you better compression without sacrificing too much image quality.  If you want smaller sizes in UIImageJPEGRepresentation, you will have to lower the quality parameter:

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5)];
```

WebP is a completely different, and much newer compressed image format, so it is likely to product smaller files as well.  If size is so much of a concern, you will also see huge size decreases if you can scale down the image before converting it to JPEG.

Comment: Well, this is exactly what I was asking... What is the connection between the different parameters. AFAIK, jpeg compression doesn't get better with more number crunching.

Comment: No, different libraries / programs use different algortithms and can produce different results.  See this article for differences between ImageMagick and Lightroom: http://www.drillio.com/en/photography/image-quality/best-jpg-quality-imagemagick-vs-lightroom/

Comment: So I guess to answer your original question more directly, is that there is no direct correlation.  One algorithm's 100% quality setting is different than any others.  They will likely be in the ballpark, but will not match.  The only other thing you can say for sure is that higher number mean higher file sizes.